# How to store and manipulate chunks of byte[] data in Java for Android (AudioRecord)

Tags: android, arrays, audiorecord

I am in no way a seasoned programmer. I have been successful at getting AudioRecord to write microphone data directly to file (as a readable .wav file) as it comes in from the mic, with the help of many code snippets from the internet.

However, for what I want to do with my app, I need to save only portions of what comes in from the mic, and I thought I would be able to do that by saving the byte data into some sort of an array first so I could selectively use what I want and save to file. Like many examples do, my class for reading microphone data reads the data into a byte array defined as:

```
byte data[] = new byte[audioBuffer];
```

and is read in with

```
read = audio.read(data, 0, audioBuffer);
```

My idea was to save each byte data array after it is read in to some sort of another array, and then read back each individual byte data array later to save to file when the user requests it. I tried an ArrayList to hold the data arrays:

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> grabArray = new ArrayList<byte[]>(grabArraySize);
```

but I am apparently only getting the last byte data array from the microphone for the whole .wav file. I am guessing I am misusing the ArrayList, but it's description sounded like the best chance of being able to do what I need. I have tried to find another way to do what I want including ByteBuffer, but that does not seem to provide the type of control that an array provides, where I can overwrite old data with new, and then at any point retrieve any or all of the data.

Basically, I know how to do this if it were simple primitives like integers or floats, but byte arrays are apparently throwing me for a loop. On top of that, there is a byte primitive, then there is the Byte class which can be wrapper... all a bunch of ??? to someone who doesn't make a living programming in Java. What is the best way to manhandle byte arrays (or just bytes for that matter) like you would do with just plain numbers?

Some more code to show how I save the audio data (in my AudioRecord thread) to a temporary holding array, then try to retrieve the data (in another class) so I can save to file: (My code is a big mess right now with comments and me trying various methods, commenting out things I'm not currently using... it would be too much to put it all here and I don't have the time to clean it up. I'm hoping this description of how I am trying to handle byte arrays will be enough to the help I need.)

Reading audio data and saving to my temporary holding array:

```
while(recordState){
    read = audio.read(data, 0, audioBuffer);
    if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
        if(i_read == grabArraySize){
            i_read = 0; // reset index to 0 if hit end of array size
        }
        grabArray.set(i_read, data);
        i_read += 1;
    }
}
```

When asked to, reading audio data back from temporary holding array so I can save to file:

```
while(i < grabArraySize - 1){ // not writing the whole array - leaving out the last chunk
    if(i_write == grabArraySize){
        i_write = 0;
    }
    os.write(tempArray.get(i_write));
    i       += 1;
    i_write += 1;
}
```

My FileOutputStream os works fine - I am successfully writing to file with the .wav header. I need to figure out how to store the data[ ] byte arrays from the AudioRecorder somewhere other than directly to a file, so that I can then retrieve them whenever I want, and then write them to file. I am successfully getting audio data, but the whole file is repeating one piece of that audio data (of size audiobuffer) over and over into whole file. The file is the correct length; everything else seems to be working; I can even recognize the sound I was making in the little bit that gets saves over and over...

Update again - It appears that ArrayLists are just pointers, as opposed to holding values like a normal array of values. I am now defining grabArray and tempArray both as byte[ ][ ]. Example - if I want to hold 10 separate byte arrays, with each byte array of size audioBuffer, I would define my array as such:

```
byte[][] grabArray = new byte[10][audioBuffer];
```

Now, in my AudioRecord thread, I am looping through my grabArray, setting each index = to the incoming audio byte array:

```
grabArray[i] = data;
```

Then, when I'm ready to write out to file, (after setting tempArray = grabArray ; I do this in case the AudioRecord thread writes a new audio chunk to the grabArray before I get to write to file) I loop through my tempArray:

```
os.write(tempArray[i]);
```

I am still getting only one instance of data[ ] (the audio chunks) repeated all throughout the file. Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: Can you post some code what you are trying?

Comment: Yes, of course - posted more. I'm sorry I'm leaving a lot out - I would rather just post the whole thing but in this case I don't think it would make anything easier - there is a lot in the code right now that is not relevant and is a bit messy. Plus, everything seems to be working accept for me being able to temporarily store the audio data byte arrays somewhere so I can later retrieve to save to file, instead of saving directly to file which I can successfully do.

Comment: Please provide your solution when you get a chance..